# use Chef file.insert_line_if_no_match method for CIDR address

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cidr

I am trying to use `file.insert_line_if_no_match` for CIDR address:

attributes/default.rb:

```
default["chefclustercidr"]["ip"] = "a.b.c.d/24"
```

recipe/default.rb

```
ruby_block "chef-backend.rb" do
block do
  file = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("/etc/chef-backend/chef-backend.rb")
  file.insert_line_if_no_match("/publish_address/" , "publish_address i#{node['chefclusterbe1']['ip']}")
  file.insert_line_if_no_match("/postgresql/" , "postgresql.md5_auth_cidr_addresses = ["samehost", "samenet", "#{node['chefclustercidr']['ip']}/24"]")
  file.write_file
  end
end
```

but getting ruby syntax error
$ruby -c default.rb

```
default.rb:95: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
th_cidr_addresses = ["samehost", "samenet","#{node['chefclus
                              ^
default.rb:95: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
resses = ["samehost", "samenet","#{node['chefclustercidr']['
                              ^
default.rb:99: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve in the third line of your block, but you have unescaped `"` as suggested by ruby. You cannot have `"` wrapper with `""`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FileEdit is an internal class and using it from recipe code is *NOT SUPPORTED*. Do not use it. Period.

That said, the problem is you have unescaped double quotes in your string.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `insert_line_if_no_match` you can deal with it another way, using bash and grep. I have added the way to another question you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51848305/how-to-update-the-file-with-multiple-lines-without-deleting-the-contents-of-the/52051405#52051405)

here is the bash resource i usually use to append to files only if there is no match:

```
bash 'append line(s) to file if it doesnt exist' do
  user 'user'
  code <<-EOS
    cat >>/home/file <<EOL
      *.* @@172.167.189.67:514
    EOL
   EOS
  not_if "grep -q 172.167.189.67 /home/file"
end
```

you may need to run cookstyle on that ^